# Loop over both the x-axis and y-axis variables in ggplot list and print plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I went through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547448/looping-over-ggplot2-with-columns) but it only loops through the x-axis, how can I loop through both x and y axis. I tried it as follows but it does not print each plot in grid:
Thanks!

For example I have a dataframe:

```
t <- data.frame(w = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x = c(23,45,23, 34), 
                y = c(23,34,54, 23), z = c(23,12,54, 32))
```

Function to get common legend on the right:

```
 grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(...) {
      plots <- list(...)
      g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position="right"))$grobs
      legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
      lw <- sum(legend$width)
      gl <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme(legend.position="none"))
      grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(grobs = gl), legend,
                   ncol = 2, widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lw, lw))
    }
```

Actual plotting loop:

```
qual = c("w", "x")
for(q in qual){
  p = lapply(list("y", "z"), function(l) ggplot(t, aes_string(x=l, y=q)) + 
               geom_point(aes(col=plate_name), size=2.0) + 
               xlab(l) + ylab(q) +
               geom_smooth(method="lm") +
               scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
               theme_bw())
  #pdf("x_vs_y_gg.pdf", h=3.5*3, w=14)
  print(grid_arrange_shared_legend(p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]], p[[4]], p[[5]], p[[6]], p[[7]], p[[8]]))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

t <- data.frame(w = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x = c(23,45,23, 34), 
                y = c(23,34,54, 23), z = c(23,12,54, 32),
                plate_name=LETTERS[1:4])

 grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(plots) {
      g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position="right"))$grobs
      legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
      lw <- sum(legend$width)
      gl <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme(legend.position="none"))
      grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(grobs = gl), legend,
                   ncol = 2, widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lw, lw))
    }

myfun <- function(l,q) ggplot(t, aes(x=get(l), y=get(q))) + 
               geom_point(aes(col=plate_name), size=2.0) + 
               xlab(l) + ylab(q) +
               geom_smooth(method="lm") +
               scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
               theme_bw()

cmb <- combn(names(t)[-ncol(t)],2)
lst <- mapply(myfun, cmb[1,], cmb[2,], SIMPLIFY = F)

grid_arrange_shared_legend(lst)
```

[image]